# SWIFTUI Core Data passing numbers

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

How can I use the numbers for calculations in SWIFTUI with CoreData? I created the Entity in the CoreData Model. The Entity is Article and I have 2 attributes one is a string Name and the other one is Price which is a Double.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class Article:NSManagedObject, Identifiable{

    @NSManaged public var name:String?
    @NSManaged public var price:String?

}
extension Article {

    static func getAllArticles() -> NSFetchRequest<Article>{

        let request:NSFetchRequest<Article> = Article.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Article>

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        return request
    } 
}
```

This is my class passing them as String is not a problem and I can use them as well, but I want to do the calculation in collection view so for example in Collection view I want to calculate the price for 4 pieces but I can't do that because they are strings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you make `price` a string if you want it to be a double?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you made price a string. Maybe you have some reasons to do it. You can count amount by converting String to Double. For example (for SwiftUI, Swift 5):

```
 func sumAmount() -> Double{
               var sum: Double = 0.0
               let allArticles = getAllArticles()
               for result in allArticles {
                   let pQ = result.value(forKey: "price") as! String
                   sum += Double(pQ) ?? 0.0
               }
               return sum
           }
```